# Spark Scala TF-IDF value sorted vectors

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

So far I have been able to tokenize all of my documents, and use CountVectorizer and IDF from Spark's MLLib. I am trying to get the top 50 words from each document, but I am not sure how to  sort the output of IDF.

onePer is a dataframe of document IDs and tokenized documents.

```
val tf = new CountVectorizer()
  .setInputCol("text")
  .setOutputCol("features").fit(onePer)
  .transform(onePer).select("features").rdd
    .map{x:Row => x.getAs[Vector](0)}

tf.cache()
val idf = new IDF().fit(tf)
val tfidf: RDD[Vector] = idf.transform(tf)
```

This is what my output looks like (number of words in vocab, id of word, word score). I would like to sort by score and get the top k:

```
(440,[0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,15,17,18,19,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,30,31,32,33,34,35,39,41,43,45,47,49,51,52,53,55,57,63,66,69,70,71,74,76,79,80,83,84,85,88,94,95,96,97,99,102,106,107,109,111,117,120,121,124,127,128,129,138,142,145,146,149,154,156,164,166,167,170,171,176,187,189,199,203,204,217,218,219,232,234,236,237,238,240,248,250,251,254,259,263,265,267,280,291,296,302,304,309,319,322,328,333,347,361,364,371,375,384,388,393,395,401,403,433,438,439],[1.3559553712291716,3.9422868018213513,0.6369074622370692,7.795697904781566,3.153829441457081,0.0,5.519201522549892,0.3184537311185346,0.3184537311185346,1.3559553712291716,0.4519851237430572,0.4519851237430572,0.6061358035703155,1.0116009116784799,0.4519851237430572,0.7884573603642703,0.4519851237430572,2.0232018233569597,0.7884573603642703,8.523740461192126,0.6061358035703155,0.6061358035703155,0.6061358035703155,0.6061358035703155,0.7884573603642703,0.6061358035703155,0.6061358035703155,0.6061358035703155,0.7884573603642703,0.7884573603642703,1.0116009116784799,1.0116009116784799,2.0232018233569597,0.7884573603642703,0.7884573603642703,3.897848952390783,0.7884573603642703,0.7884573603642703,1.0116009116784799,5.114244276715276,1.0116009116784799,1.0116009116784799,2.5985659682605218,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.0116009116784799,1.0116009116784799,1.0116009116784799,1.0116009116784799,1.0116009116784799,2.5985659682605218,1.0116009116784799,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,3.4094961844768505,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,3.4094961844768505,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,3.4094961844768505,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253])
```

#### Update

I was able to get this working by doing the following:

```
tfidf.map(x => x.toSparse).map{x => x.indices.zip(x.values)
  .sortBy(-_._2)
  .take(10)
  .map(_._1)
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use HashingTF instead of the CountVectorizer and set the number of features you want to keep ?

Comment: I need to be able to map back to the original word, so hashing isn't an option for me unfortunately.

Comment: You can keep those information with DataFrame if you use spark-ml. Unfortunate I have no access to a computer now to write the example code.

Comment: @eliasah What information should I keep in a DataFrame? If you are referring to the mapping of words to hash, I have a strict requirement for no collisions. My concern would still be how to sort the values of IDF though.

Comment: I understand your concern. @tuxda 's answer should solve your problem then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help:

```
scala> val x = (440,Array[Int](0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,15,17,18,19,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,30,31,32,33,34,35,39,41,43,45,47,49,51,52,53,55,57,63,66,69,70,71,74,76,79,80,83,84,85,88,94,95,96,97,99,102,106,107,109,111,117,120,121,124,127,128,129,138,142,145,146,149,154,156,164,166,167,170,171,176,187,189,199,203,204,217,218,219,232,234,236,237,238,240,248,250,251,254,259,263,265,267,280,291,296,302,304,309,319,322,328,333,347,361,364,371,375,384,388,393,395,401,403,433,438,439),Array[Double](1.3559553712291716,3.9422868018213513,0.6369074622370692,7.795697904781566,3.153829441457081,0.0,5.519201522549892,0.3184537311185346,0.3184537311185346,1.3559553712291716,0.4519851237430572,0.4519851237430572,0.6061358035703155,1.0116009116784799,0.4519851237430572,0.7884573603642703,0.4519851237430572,2.0232018233569597,0.7884573603642703,8.523740461192126,0.6061358035703155,0.6061358035703155,0.6061358035703155,0.6061358035703155,0.7884573603642703,0.6061358035703155,0.6061358035703155,0.6061358035703155,0.7884573603642703,0.7884573603642703,1.0116009116784799,1.0116009116784799,2.0232018233569597,0.7884573603642703,0.7884573603642703,3.897848952390783,0.7884573603642703,0.7884573603642703,1.0116009116784799,5.114244276715276,1.0116009116784799,1.0116009116784799,2.5985659682605218,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.0116009116784799,1.0116009116784799,1.0116009116784799,1.0116009116784799,1.0116009116784799,2.5985659682605218,1.0116009116784799,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,3.4094961844768505,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,3.4094961844768505,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,3.4094961844768505,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.2992829841302609,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253,1.7047480922384253))

scala> val (r, indices, values) = x
r: Int = 440
indices: Array[Int] = Array(0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 52, 53, 55, 57, 63, 66, 69, 70, 71, 74, 76, 79, 80, 83, 84, 85, 88, 94, 95, 96, 97, 99, 102, 106, 107, 109, 111, 117, 120, 121, 124, 127, 128, 129, 138, 142, 145, 146, 149, 154, 156, 164, 166, 167, 170, 171, 176, 187, 189, 199, 203, 204, 217, 218, 219, 232, 234, 236, 237, 238, 240, 248, 250, 251, 254, 259, 263, 265, 267, 280, 291, 296, 302, 304, 309, 319, 322, 328, 333, 347, 361, 364, 371, 375, 384, 388, 393, 395, 401, 403, 433, 438, 439)
values: Array[Double] = Array(1.3559553712291716, 3.9422868018213513, 0.6369074622370692, 7.795697904781566, 3.153829441457081, 0.0, 5.519201522549892, 0.3184537311185346, 0.31845373...

scala> val topTermIds = indices.zip(values).sortBy( - _._2).take(50).map(_._1)
topTermIds: Array[Int] = Array(26, 4, 7, 63, 2, 52, 109, 124, 138, 5, 70, 85, 24, 47, 176, 187, 189, 199, 203, 204, 217, 218, 219, 232, 234, 236, 237, 238, 240, 248, 250, 251, 254, 259, 263, 265, 267, 280, 291, 296, 302, 304, 309, 319, 322, 328, 333, 347, 361, 364)
```

Now you need to plug in above code into a closure, something like:

```
val topTermsByScore = rdd.map { v: Vector =>
    // to sort decreasing use - 
    v.indices.zip(v.values).sortBy( - _._2).take(50).map(_._1)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up having to convert my RDD[Vector] to a sparse vector first, but then I could access indices and values, zip them and sort.

Comment: @Ashley When you are dealing with matrices, you should always check for its nature sparse or not. That's very important for scalability and performance issues. You can read more about it [here](http://qr.ae/ROh76y).

Comment: @Ashley From your code output it was clear that the output is actually from a sparse vector.

Comment: How do I retrieve the original word given an index?

Comment: @Gevorg Could you create a SO question for your use-case with some sample code snippet, and link it here ?

Comment: @Gevorg well, if you have access to model, then you can do `model.vocabulary(termId)`  - https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizerModel@vocabulary:Array[String]